Error using upx to compress a Visual Foxpro Exe
I am trying UPX to see if I can reduce the size of my exe, I get the error upx: ramsys.exe: NotCompressibleException.
I have ensured the exe is not encrypted, does anyone know if this app is compatible and if not any that may be?
upx ramsyslt.exe
Hoping to find a smaller but still usable exe

How big is the EXE you are trying to compress? UPX won't work with anything under 40KB
